# Terraria: "decorated" demon eyes

Tags: terraria

There are different colored demon eyes, and some are normal with accessories and I just want to know if they have different stats than others or if it's just a random little addition. Pls no hate.

Answer (score 1):

[**Demon Eye Purple**](http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/terraria/images/7/73/Demon_Eye_Purple.gif/revision/latest?cb=20140724034117)
Same as Demon Eye, just 45 health.

[**Demon Eye Black**](http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/terraria/images/e/ed/Demon_Eye_Black.gif/revision/latest?cb=20140724034305)
Not guaranteed to drop Black Lenses. Appearance is false. (same as normal one)

[**Demon Eye Green**](http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/terraria/images/a/a6/Demon_Eye_Green.gif/revision/latest?cb=20140724034235)
51 health. A possible reference to the Super Mario series, where a green mushroom gives an extra life.

[**Demon Eye Yellow**](http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/terraria/images/6/62/Demon_Eye_Yellow.gif/revision/latest?cb=20140724034317)
Doesn't actually drop white lenses. Appearance is false. (Same as normal one)

[**Demon Eye Monoeye**](http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/terraria/images/e/ef/Demon_Eye_Monoeye.gif/revision/latest?cb=20140724034247)
Demon Eye with 66 health. A possible reference to Monoeyes from the Kid Icarus series.

Sorry some pictures are so small.

EOC: [**The official wiki**](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Eye_of_Cthulhu) Will give you some infomation on the EOC.

The Eye of Cthulhu can be summoned manually using a [**Suspicious Looking Eye**](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Suspicious_Looking_Eye) at Night. It also has a 1 in 3 chance of spawning automatically each night once the following conditions are met:

- At least one player in the world has at least 200 life and more than 10 defense.
- At least three Town NPCs are acquired.
- The Eye of Cthulhu has not yet been defeated in the current world.

Its approach is signaled with the message: `"You feel an evil presence watching you..."` Within 20-40 seconds of this message, the Eye of Cthulhu will appear and begin attacking the player. If the Eye is not defeated by dawn, or if all players die or run away while fighting it, it despawns.

To make the eye, you need 6 [**lenses**](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Lens) and a [**demon/crimson alter**](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Demon_Altar).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got real worried something like eye of cutchulu would spawn! (Sorry if I spelled EOC wrong)

Comment: Wait, let me just edit my answer about EOC for you.

Comment: There ya go, sorry it's so much :P

Comment: Thanks for the help! The guide did keep saying things about lenses and a demon alter.

Comment: yep that'll be it! How far are you into the game? Like health/defense/attack wise?

Comment: I have a tungsten broadsword, 10 defense, 20 red hearts.

Comment: And a hornet pet

Comment: I just got a message sayin

Comment: Please avoid long discussions in comments

Comment: yeah, last comment You should be fine about the EOC until you spawn it, no need to worry about it spawning randomly ;)

Comment: Thx 4 the help!